# Is Jquery post during window beforeunload event a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting my web app to post a small (200 bytes) JSON file with a few user settings back to the server when the user closes the browser window or navigates away ( `$(window).on('beforeunload')` ). Post call is:

```
$.post('/backendscript', { mydata: jsonstr });
```

so no waiting for a callback. Just wondering if this is bad for some unforseen reason, e.g. could hold up browser from closing, or browser window could shut down before data sent, etc.?

Thanks

Comment: Yes is bad idea if request is important. Numerous reasons this may never get sent...browser freeze, power fail, no internet connection at that moment ...etc

Comment: if you use websockets, the server can know when a user goes offline via the 'closed' event.